# Using Apache Solr for Project Archive

Tags: solr, project, search-engine, archive

In our company there are many projects that are all contain several informations, e.g. source code, project informations, bug reports or emails. The informations are not on a central place so if you want to search for a solved problem in a past project, you have to search for yourself.

The idea is now to build a project archive that you can search through. We want to use Apache Solr to create a Webapp with which you can search for several informations.

Indexing pdf, word or java files is not the problem in this case. The question is, what is the best solution to gather all the files from different systems. The documents are present in systems like MS Sharepoint, Atlassian Confluence, Jira, SVN or Git.

What is the best strategy to export all the informations from the different systems to gather them in a central place, where the indexing can easily be done, maybe automatically.

Comment: Would something like [Apache Manifold](http://manifoldcf.apache.org/en_US/index.html#What+Is+Apache+ManifoldCF%3F) help you? It [contains connectors](http://manifoldcf.apache.org/release/release-1.7/en_US/included-connectors.html) to so some of the sources you mention.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like a good alternative, but the problem is, that for every new system that is established to archive project informations, you have to set up a new connector. It would be better to seperate the project archive from the other systems.